# Story where scientists are prosecuted for time machine exploding

Tags: story-identification

The plot is essentially a plea by two scientists to a courtroom.
They are being prosecuted for blowing up a government project and half of Arizona. They were the builders of a time travel device and had returned to their office  late one evening and found an intruder operating the machine. 
The intruder's note says he has gone to 1st Century Jerusalem to rescue Christ from crucifixion.
The physics of the device mean stopping the intruder means that the machine goes bang...
Does it seem familiar to anyone?

Answer (score 25):

This is [The Rescuer](http://www.unz.org/Pub/AnalogSF-1962jul-00154) by Arthur Porges.

> The story can be divided into 2 parts. In the first part of the story
>   there is a description of the “time-machine”, in fact the author talks
>   about the development, the characteristics and the cost of the special
>   machine. In the second part of the story there is a report regarding
>   the “Preliminary Hearing”: the USA court versus Dr Carnot and Dr Kent.
>   Judge Clark asks Dr Carnot a series of questions about the destruction
>   of the time-machine. Dr Carnot reveals to the court that he and Dr
>   Kent had destroyed the time-machine because a “madman”, Michael Nauss,
>   wanted to go back to the past to rescue Jesus Christ from the Roman
>   soldiers in order to save him from crucifixion. Nauss had very good
>   chances of succeeding because he brought with him a repeating rifle.
>   The two scientists feared the consequences of Nauss’s action on the
>   whole path of history in the lost two thousand years and therefore
>   destroyed the time-machine. (ln 158: A little change at the source can
>   make a tremendous difference at the mouth). The situation was very
>   dangerous and there was no time to lose. They wanted to prevent him
>   arriving in the past. As the present is linked to the past, he could
>   change the course of history.

You can read most of it online [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ogpl_8TplUEC&pg=PT587&lpg=PT587&dq=%22It%20was%20by%20far%20the%20largest,%20most%20intricate%20machine%20ever%22&source=bl&ots=EjlKkJNc_a&sig=qe9MFeZd7dmS3RyjGs-3W8hWH4E&hl=en&sa=X&ei=PNDGVOONHomAU9TlgJgG&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22It%20was%20by%20far%20the%20largest%2C%20most%20intricate%20machine%20ever%22&f=false).

Comment: Richard, spot on, that's it! Well done and thank you.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as "accepted" :-)

Comment: the link at the end takes me to a google book search for "It was by far the largest, most intricate machine ever"

Comment: @Malachi - Yes, the book is still on copyright so the best you'll find online (from a legal source) is google books which contains a substantial preview of the story.